# NodeJS fetch failed (object2 is not iterable) when uploading file via POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, fetch-api

I'm trying to upload a file using native fetch in NodeJS (added in node 17.5, see https://nodejs.org/ko/blog/release/v17.5.0/).

However, I keep getting the following error -

```
TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.processResponse (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5536:34)
at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5858:42
at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:202:9)
at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
cause: TypeError: object2 is not iterable
at action (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1660:39)
at action.next (<anonymous>)
at Object.pull (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1708:52)
at ensureIsPromise (node:internal/webstreams/util:172:19)
at readableStreamDefaultControllerCallPullIfNeeded
node:internal/webstreams/readablestream:1884:5)
at node:internal/webstreams/readablestream:1974:7
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I'm using the following code to create and submit the form response -

```js
function upload(hub_entity_id, document_path) {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("type", "Document");
  formData.append("name", "ap_test_document.pdf");
  formData.append("file", fs.createReadStream("ap_test_document.pdf"));
  formData.append("entity_object_id", hub_entity_id);

  const form_headers = {
    Authorization: auth_code,
    ...formData.getHeaders(),
  };

  console.log(
    `Uploading document ap_test_document.pdf to hub (${hub_entity_id}) `
  );
  console.log(formData);

  let raw_response = await fetch(urls.attachments, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: form_headers,
    body: formData,
  });

  console.log(raw_response);
}
```

Comment: Looks like it might be a problem with `fs.createReadStream()`. Why do you have two of them? Have you checked that the file path is correct?

Comment: @Phil my bad, shouldnt have left that in. Took that out and I'm still getting that error so I've updated the original question. Yep checked the file path and it looks ok.

Comment: What version of nodeJS are you using?

Comment: @Ukor this is in node v18.5

Comment: Hey @HarrisonBroadbent, were you able to solve this issue? I am having the same error and I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I'm getting the same error uploading a file using fetch.

Comment: I think you can try with stream that containes whole formdata `const stream = new stream.Readable();
stream.push(formData);
stream.push(null);

let raw_response = await fetch(urls.attachments, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: form_headers,
  body: stream,
});`

Comment: @NIKUNJKOTHIYA: `new stream.Readable()` gives an error "The _read() method is not implemented".

Comment: you need to import before use `const { Readable } = require('stream');`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Issue with form-data package:

The *formData* structure is not parseable by Node.js, so it throws: `object2 is not iterable`.

On the other hand, the sad story is *formData* will not be maintained anymore,
and you may have noticed that two years have passed since the last version was published. So they officially announced that *formData* will be archived:
[The final nail in the coffin of formData](https://github.com/form-data/form-data/issues/537).

> Will this be the time for deprecation? form-data haven't been updated in a while and it still lacks some method that should be provided according to the spec. node-fetch@3 stopp recommended ppl using form-data due to inconsistency with spec compatible FormData and recommend that ppl use built in FormData or a spec:ed formdata polyfill that supports iterating over all fields and having Blob/File support

---

### Solutions

### **1. using [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) package:**

So in simple words, we need to somehow convert the *form-data* stream to a node.js stream. This can be done with the help of some stream methods as follows:

**stream.Transform:**

With the `stream.Transform` class from Node.js stream and passing the *form-data* instance, we can send the request with the built-in fetch API.

from Node.js doc:

> Transform streams are Duplex streams where the output is in some way related to the input. Like all Duplex streams, Transform streams implement both the Readable and Writable interfaces.

So we can achieve it like this:

```js
import { Transform } from 'stream';

// rest of code

const tr = new Transform({
  transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    callback(null, chunk);
  },
});
formData.pipe(tr);

const request = new Request(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: form_headers,
  duplex: 'half',
  body: tr
})

let raw_response = await fetch(request);
```

**stream.PassThrough**:

Instead of returning each chunk of stream, We can simply use `stream.PassThrough`:

```js
import { PassThrough } from 'stream';

// rest of code

const pt = new PassThrough()
formData.pipe(pt);

const request = new Request(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: form_headers,
  duplex: 'half',
  body: pt
})

let raw_response = await fetch(request);
```

**Important note**: If you don't pass `duplex: 'half'`, you would get this error:

```
duplex option is required when sending a body
```

### **2. using built-in [form-data](https://undici.nodejs.org/)**

Currently, the part of the Node.js core that handles *fetch* is named [undici](https://github.com/nodejs/undici).

Luckily, you don't need to use any third-party module for handling any form-data, since *undici* has implemented it and is now a part of Node.js core.

Sadly, working with part of *undici* streaming is not easy and straightforward. However, you can still achieve it.

```js
import { Readable } from 'stream';
// For now, it is essential for encoding the header part, or you can skip importing this module and instead implement it by yourself. 
import { FormDataEncoder } from 'form-data-encoder';

// This is a built-in FormData class, as long as you're using Node.js version 18.x and above, 
// no need to import any third-party form-data packages from NPM.
const formData = new FormData();
formData.set('file', {
  name: 'ap_test_document.pdf',
  [Symbol.toStringTag]: 'File',
  stream: () => fs.createReadStream(filePath) 
});

const encoder = new FormDataEncoder(formData)

const request = new Request(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'content-type': encoder.contentType,
    Authorization: auth_code
  },
  duplex: 'half',
  body: Readable.from(encoder)
})
let raw_response = await fetch(request);
```

**P.S**:
You may need to read [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/undici/issues/963), for the part about encoding.

Comment: This works even if you use `fetch({url, {method: "POST", body: formData})`, without a need for the `FormDataEncoder`.

Comment: The trick is the `[Symbol.toStringTag]: 'File'`, which makes `FormData` accept the object with the `stream` method as a Blob/File, see [here](https://github.com/nodejs/undici/blob/f9aa0f186c9b1bc2cf2f492159da7c07113198d2/lib/core/util.js#L20-L28).

Comment: Can you also compress the file while uploading?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Theißen I didn't try it! however, since [zlib](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html) supports *stream*, it shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: Have you tried this: `const compress = createGzip(); formData.set('file', { /*...*/  stream: () => fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(compress) })`?

Comment: Moreover, your suggestion compresses the _file_, but I have to compress the entire `multipart/form-data` payload.

Comment: That would be a different thing, compressing the whole request may be handled by the *gzip* header field. And about the *size*, it is optional in this case and the `content-length` is calculated by the `form-data-encoder`. You may need to read how [form-data-encoder](https://github.com/octet-stream/form-data-encoder) calculates the size in stream mode.

Comment: Calculating the size for the `content-length` header and streaming do not go together. To know the size you would have to consume the entire readable stream _before_ sending the header, and only afterwards can you send the first chunk.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of

```js
new Request(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: ...,
  duplex: 'half',
  body: ...
})
```

in Mostafa Fakhraei's answer is necessary to avoid errors caused by the absence of a `size` attribute in the `formData.set` statement. See also [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/nodejs/undici/issues/1934), including the comment which considers this approach a misuse of `FormData`.

### Why would this be a misuse of FormData?

I believe this is because including a file stream in an HTTP request in this way leads to a chunked request, which many servers do not support, as explained [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/170688/trying-to-do-a-chunked-multipart-post-request-nginx-and-php-both-returns-400-er). `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` is generally supported only for responses, not for requests.

### The legitimate use

```js
fetch(new Request(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
}));
```

sets the `Content-Length` header based on the `formData`'s `size` attribute and *then* reads and sends the file chunk-by-chunk (without keeping the entire file in memory). Thanks to the presence of the `Content-Length` header, this still produces a non-chunked request, as demonstrated by this program:

```js
var formData = new FormData();
var stream = fs.createReadStream(filepath);
stream.on("data", function(chunk) {
  console.log("<", chunk.length);
});
formData.append("file", {
  [Symbol.toStringTag]: "File",
  size: fs.statSync(filepath).size, // size is necessary
  stream: () => stream
});
var r = new Request("http://localhost:8080", {
  method: "POST",
  body: formData
});
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  console.log("Transfer-Encoding", req.headers["transfer-encoding"]);
  req.on("data", function(chunk) {
    console.log(">", chunk.length);
  });
})
.listen(8080, function() {
  fetch(r);
});
```

This logs something like

```
< 65536
< 65536
< 65536
Transfer-Encoding undefined
> 65254 multipart header Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"
> 65536
> 65536
> 411
< 65536
< 65536
> 65536
> 65536
... many more such "two-in/two-out quartets"
< 9633 the last chunk
> 9633
> 44 the last line of the multipart body
```

But this works only if `formData` has the `size` attribute, otherwise it gives an "invalid content-length header" error.

This error can be circumvented if `fetch(r)` is replaced by

```js
fetch(r.url, r);
```

This variant does not need the `size` but always gives a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` request without `Content-Length` header, whether `size` is given or not, even if the given size is small: The final multipart line

```
------formdata-undici-0.61749873xxx56806--
```

is then always a `Transfer-Encoding` chunk of its own.

Comment: Thanks, this saved a lot of time for me. `uwsgi` server seems to not support chunked requests even after passing `--http-raw-body --http-chunked-input` flags :(

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this type of formdata issue in react app. After using single quote instead of double quote resolved my issue.

Try this:

formData.append('type', "Document");

formData.append('name', "ap_test_document.pdf");

formData.append('file', fs.createReadStream("ap_test_document.pdf"));

formData.append('entity_object_id', hub_entity_id);

Let me know if this solved your problem or not.

Comment: Is the `formData` an instance of the [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) or of the built-in `FormData`?

Answer (score 0):

Full credit to Mostafa Fakhraei for the example, but for anyone who needs a full example especially with something like formidable and Next.js see the following code. I spent a few hours trying to figure this out even with the help above so thought I'd post the full thing.

Note at least for me the duplex property on fetch was giving my IDE a type error. If you're on Node 18+ don't worry about that and add a // @ts-ignore

```
import FormData from 'form-data';
import formidable from 'formidable';
import fs from 'fs';
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { Transform } from 'stream';


const avatarUpload = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    try {
        const parseFile = () =>
            new Promise<formidable.Files>((resolve, reject) => {
                const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
                form.parse(req, async (err, _fields, files) => {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    resolve(files);
                });
            });

        const files = await parseFile();
        const formidableFile = Array.isArray(files.file) ? files.file[0] : files.file;
        const file = fs.createReadStream(formidableFile.filepath);

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);


        const tr = new Transform({
            transform(chunk, _encoding, callback) {
                callback(null, chunk);
            },
        });
        formData.pipe(tr);

        // this is for cloudflare images api. you can use any other image upload api
        const imageReq = await fetch('https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/23a1b30d95b2ebe5e7f5fce83318994c/images/v1', {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.CLOUDFLARE_IMAGE_API_KEY}`,
                ...formData.getHeaders(),
            },
            method: 'POST',
            body: tr as any,
            duplex: 'half',
        });
        // do what you want with the imageObject here

        const imageObject = (await imageReq.json()).result;


        return res.status(200).json({ imageObject });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Something went wrong' });
    }
};

export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        avatarUpload(req, res);
    } else {
        // Handle any other HTTP method
    }
}

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    },
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Use fs.readFileSync instead of createReadStream

> formData.append("file", fs.readFileSync("ap_test_document.pdf"));

Also you can use filename direct in formData.append

> formData.append("file", fs.readFileSync("ap_test_document.pdf"), "ap_test_document.pdf");

Comment: This is bad advice. Using a read stream and loading the entire file into memory using readFile/readFileSync are not equivalent actions.