# Unable to use createReadStream with Node 18 FormData

Tags: node.js, typescript, multipartform-data

Previously to Node 18 releasing [fetch/FormData](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/v18-release-announce/#fetch-experimental) we could do:

```
import FormData from 'form-data'

const form = new FormData();
form.append('my_field', 'my value');
form.append('my_buffer', new Buffer(10));
form.append('my_file', fs.createReadStream('/foo/bar.jpg'));
```

However with the global FormData I can no longer pass a stream - the error at the "my_file" line is:

> Argument of type 'ReadStream' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'

I know this is still experimental so potentially a bug or is there an alternative way to do this - besides reading the entire file as a string...

Comment: It looks like the new built-in FormData supports a `ReadableStream` (from the webStream interface) to be compatible with the browser and that's different than a `ReadStream`.

Comment: @jfriend00 where did you see that? The [doco I found](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v19.x/docs/api/globals.html#class-formdata) is **very** light-on

Comment: I saw it [here](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/v18-release-announce/#fetch-experimental) in the nodejs v18 highlights page.

Comment: @jfriend00 I get a similar error if I try to pass a `ReadableStream`. Just says string or Blob. - Also not seeing that in the provided link - can you elucidate how that might be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node v18's native [FormData](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/globals.html#class-formdata) is an implementation of the w3 [FormData interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) so you need to use that API.

The `append()` method accepts a `Blob` so you should be able to use the [`blob` stream consumer](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/webstreams.html#webstreams_streamconsumers_blob_stream)

```js
import { createReadStream } from 'node:fs';
import { blob } from 'node:stream/consumers';

// assuming a valid async context for brevity
const file = await blob(createReadStream("/foo/bar.jpg"));

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("my_file", file, "bar.jpg");
```

Comment: This undermines "streams" idea as the whole content is written to memory

Comment: @RomanRoman excellent point but I don't think Node's `FormData` / `Blob` supports streams at this time

Comment: FormData and Blob can carry streams, it's not a problem. The problem is to find out how fetch or other http libraries work with them. For example, here is how the native fetch does it:

https://github.com/nodejs/undici/blob/main/lib/fetch/body.js#L154

Comment: Streams without known size lead to chunked requests, which many servers do not support. But with known size it works, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75339195/16462950).

Answer (score 4):

Here is the implementation of pure streaming without reading the entire content in memory.

Node.JS [built-in API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/globals.html#class-formdata):

```js
import { open } from 'node:fs/promises';
import { File } from 'buffer';
  
const handle = await open('/path/to/your/file');

const stat = await handle.stat();

class MyFile extends File {
    // we should set correct size
    // otherwise we will encounter UND_ERR_REQ_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
    size = stat.size;
}

const file = new MyFile([], 'file-name')


file.stream = function() {
    return handle.readableWebStream();
};

const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('file_key', file);

fetch('http://localhost', {
    method: 'post',
    body: formData
});
```

Using [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch):

```js
import * as fs from 'fs';
import fetch, { FormData, File  } from 'node-fetch';

const stream = fs.createReadStream('/path/to/your/file');
const stat = fs.statSync('/path/to/your/file');

class MyFile extends File {
    size = stat.size;
}

const file = new MyFile([], 'file-name');

file.stream = function() {
    return stream;
};

const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('file_key', file);

fetch('http://localhost', {
    method: 'post',
    body: formData
});
```

Comment: This is awesome! However, how would you handle this error?
`(node:91559) [DEP0137] DeprecationWarning: Closing a FileHandle object on garbage collection is deprecated. Please close FileHandle objects explicitly using FileHandle.prototype.close(). In the future, an error will be thrown if a file descriptor is closed during garbage collection.`

Comment: @eliw00d You should manually call `handle.close();`

Comment: Of course, but where? The file is passed to fetch, which calls the stream method. I have tried closing the handle after getting readableWebStream from it, but I get errors. I also tried converting the readableWebStream to a readable, then listening to its close event, and then converting the readable back to a readableWebStream and returning that, but then my app crashes. This is all using the native approach, so it would be great to have an example of that.

Comment: @eliw00d You could use the `ReadableStream` wrapper over `handle.readableWebStream()`, which will allow you to call `handle.close();` when the handle.readableWebStream() is ended. A similar idea like [here](https://github.com/nodejs/undici/blob/c415fbbb59e2b898c5db6a681265cf3da865d02c/lib/fetch/body.js#L215)

Comment: I should mention that I was trying to put your first example into a utility function that I can reuse in multiple places. However, I'm thinking it might be better to return the handle and the file together and have the user of the utility function close the handle. I was originally hoping to be able to listen to the `close` event of the stream to close the handle then, but it crashes Node. I am not sure what to take from the link you provided or the wrapper, so if you have any additional thoughts let me know.

Answer (score 2):

## Node.js 19.8+

You can use [fs.openAsBlob](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsopenasblobpath-options).

```
import { openAsBlob } from 'node:fs/promises';
const blob = await openAsBlob('the.file.txt');
```

Then, you can append the file-backed blob to your form data.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', blob, name);
```

## Node.js < 19.8

We were unable to find a CommonJS-compatible streaming Blob implementation, so we took inspiration from @roman-rodionov's answer and created a library that will create a streamable `File`. If using Node.js@<18.15 you'll also need to [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@web-std/file) [File](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#class-file).

You can install [node-streamable-file](https://github.com/BugSplat-Git/node-streamable-file) to do this.

```bash
npm i node-streamable-file
```

We made a few tweaks to the implementation, most notably we removed the extra class definition. Here's our implementation if you'd like to do streaming file uploads without adding a dependency.

```
import { File } from 'buffer';
import { open } from 'node:fs/promises';
import { basename } from 'node:path';

export async function createStreamableFile(path: string): Promise<File> {
    const name = basename(path);
    const handle = await open(path);
    const { size } = await handle.stat();

    const file = new File([], name);
    file.stream = () => handle.readableWebStream();

    // Set correct size otherwise, fetch will encounter UND_ERR_REQ_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
    Object.defineProperty(file, 'size', { get: () => size });

    return file;
}
```

Use `createStreamableFile` like so

```
const formData = new FormData();
const file = await createStreamableFile('path/to/file');
formData.append('file', file);

await fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
});
```

Additionally, if you're using TypeScript there's an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52166) with the `File` and `Blob` types. You can fix the problem by casting to the instance of `File` to `unknown` and then to `Blob`.

Comment: How do you handle stream errors in this case?

Answer (score -1):

@eliw00d regarding the native node fetch implementation suggested by @romanr: I stumbled across the same issue (`Please close FileHandle objects explicitly`), and was also not able to create a `new ReadableStream` that calls the `handle.close()` method as suggested. My solution was to `import {finished} from 'node:stream'` and then add it:

```
file.stream = function () {
    const webStream = handle.readableWebStream();
    // Ensure that the handle gets closed!
    const cleanup = finished(webStream, (_err) => {
        handle.close();
        cleanup();
    });
    return webStream;
};
```

This seems to work.

Answer (score -1):

## The correct way

The most straight forward way without any dependencies is to use [fs.openAsBlob(path, {type})](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/fs.html#fsopenasblobpath-options)
It will return a `Promise<Blob>` and this also require NodeJS v20+

You don't actually need a `File` instance cuz `FormData.append()` accepts blobs too. `fd.append('field', blob, filename)`. fyi, This also works in browsers.

```js
import fs from 'node:fs'

const pkg = await fs.openAsBlob('./package.json')
const blob = await fs.openAsBlob('./README.md', { type: 'text/plain' })

// You don't really need a File (see example below by appending blobs)
const file = new File([pkg], 'package.json', { type: 'application/json' })

const fd = new FormData()
fd.append('files', blob, 'README.md') // Blobs works as well
fd.append('files', file)
```

I would say this is the proper way to get hold of a blob without reading any of the content into memory. or by extending files and overriding the `stream` method with a custom function, cuz that's wrong. and should best be avoided.

## The `node-fetch` way.

If you are using [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) then it already comes with ways to create blob from paths. and it works all the way from NodeJS v14+

```js
import fetch, {
  Blob, blobFrom, blobFromSync,
  File, fileFrom, fileFromSync,
  FormData
} from 'node-fetch'

const fd = new FormData()
fd.append('files', fileFromSync('./README.md'))
fd.append('files', await fileFrom('./package.json', 'text/plain'))
```

This utility method dose not really come from `node-fetch`, but actually from [fetch-blob](https://github.com/node-fetch/fetch-blob). so this `blobFrom` and `fileFrom` can be used without installing `node-fetch`

```js
import {
  Blob, blobFrom, blobFromSync,
  File, fileFrom, fileFromSync, 
  createTemporaryBlob, createTemporaryFile 
} from 'fetch-blob/from.js'
```