# Node.js FormData and File references

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, form-data, whatwg-streams-api

Suppose I want to use the Fetch API to upload a local file as part of FormData with Node.js.

If this were a browser, I might have a file or blob reference already, such as from a [file input element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_API/Using_files_from_web_applications#getting_information_about_selected_files).  In that case, I just append the file reference to the FormData instance, and the user agent takes care of streaming it from disk, like so:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', fileInputElement.files[0]);

const res = await fetch(postURL, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
});
```

Now, in the Node.js case, there is no file input element.  All I have is a path on disk.  How can I get a Blob or File reference from that?

Some things I've looked into:

- A simple [`fs.open()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/fs.html#fsopenpath-flags-mode-callback) returns a FileHandle which is not something FormData can use.
- A [ReadableStream](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/webstreams.html#class-readablestream) can't be used directly either.
- The [Blob Stream Consumers](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/webstreams.html#new-readablestreamunderlyingsource--strategy) utility will allow me to create a Blob from a ReadableStream, but it does this by [buffering the entire contents of the stream in memory](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/lib/stream/consumers.js#L29-L34).  That won't work as I'm uploading files that are multiple gigabytes.

Is there any way to get a File reference that FormData can use, for a local file on disk, with Node.js?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76026397/283366) answer your question?