# How to send multiple large files as streams to server from Node.js?

Tags: node.js, http, stream, multipartform-data, filestream

Is there a way to use something like this in Node.js with basic APIs?

```
const fileStream1 = fs.readFileSync('tmp/large.2gb.file.gz')
const fileStream2 = fs.readFileSync("tmp/large.10gb.file.gz");

const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('file1', fileStream1)
formData.append("file2", fileStream2);

fetch('/upload', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
})
```

And have it stream the files? All of the examples I've seen, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/76957447/169992, read the file into memory and set it in `append('file', blobOrFile)`, and the MDN docs say it's a File or Blob only. How else can you accomplish multiple streaming file uploads in Node.js? If you get lower level to the `https` module, can you do it there somehow?

That last link seems like a hack, not sure that is the way to go:

```
export async function createStreamableFile(
  path: string,
): Promise<File> {
  const name = basename(path)
  const handle = await open(path)
  const { size } = await handle.stat()

  const file = new File([], name)
  file.stream = () => handle.readableWebStream() as ReadableStream

  // Set correct size otherwise, fetch will encounter UND_ERR_REQ_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
  Object.defineProperty(file, 'size', { get: () => size })

  return file
}
```