# Streaming multipart/form-data request with native fetch in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I'm trying to stream a file to an API using a multipart/form-data request with native fetch in Node.js.

Here's how you can upload the file after reading the whole file into memory:

```js
const { readFile } = require('fs/promises')

async function upload() {
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('user_id', 42)
    formData.append('audio', new Blob([await readFile('./music.mp3')]))

    const response = await fetch('http://api.example.com', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
    })
}
```

This works.

However, is there a way to upload the file without reading it entirely into memory with something like `fs.createReadStream()`?

For example, something like this would be nice if it worked:

```js
formData.append('audio', fs.createReadStream('./music.mp3'))
```

It seems like libraries like `node-fetch` and `request` support this, but I'd like to do it natively if possible.

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://developer.chrome.com/articles/fetch-streaming-requests/#streaming-request-bodies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you'd modify the code above to stream a file upload using native FormData and fetch:

```js
const { createReadStream } = require('fs')

async function upload() {
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('user_id', 42)
    formData.set('audio', {
        [Symbol.toStringTag]: 'File',
        name: 'music.mp3',
        stream: () => createReadStream('./music.mp3'),
    })

    const response = await fetch('http://api.example.com', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
    })
}
```

Comment: This `Symbol.toStringTag` thing seems like a hack. Could one derive a class from `File` and add the method there? Also, is interesting to know *why* it works, — is there a documentation on it?

Comment: DOM APIs, like File, in Node are incredibly limited and generally rely on hacks until Node's API provides conversion helpers. A good example is `require('stream').Readable.toWeb(nodeStream)`. I'd love a cleaner solution, but this does work.

Comment: Btw, here is the line of code in node's fetch impl that the `Symbol.toStringTag` hack is targetting: https://github.com/nodejs/undici/blob/f9aa0f186c9b1bc2cf2f492159da7c07113198d2/lib/core/util.js#L26

Comment: More discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72568850/nodejs-fetch-failed-object2-is-not-iterable-when-uploading-file-via-post-reque

Comment: Upon further inspection, the first thing that that function (`isBlobLike`) does is `object instanceof Blob`. All instances of `Blob` [have `.stream()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/stream). So, the trick with `Symbol.toStringTag` seems unnecessary.

Comment: The problem was that I didn't know how to create a Blob with a custom stream() method since the API gives you no constructor for that... but you can just create an empty Blob and assign `blob.stream = () => myStream`! Thanks, I updated the answer.

Comment: i actually had a revert the change. for some reason the upload doesn't work. my test just wasn't testing it when i tried it. will look into it later.

Comment: With this I get the error:
> invalid content-length header